# Colocar logo y mostrar informacion de usuario en reporte con datatables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Quisiera saber como se pudiese colocar un logo y la informacion de un usuario que realiza una exportacion de informacion al seleccionar el boton PDF o el boton IMPRIMIR que son de datatables de jquery?

Para los botones yo solo tengo lo siguiente:

```
            buttons: [
{
                extend: 'print',
                text: 'IMPRIMIR',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
},





{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            text: 'EXCEL',
            exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible',
                            modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                                    }
                             }

},
{

            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            text: 'PDF',
            orientation: 'portrait',
            pageSize: 'LETTER',
            title: 'Reporte de Citas Procesadas', 
            exportOptions: {
                            columns: ':visible',
                            modifier: {
                            page: 'current'
                                    }
                             },


},

            'colvis'
        ],

        columnDefs: [ {
            visible: false
        } ]


    } );
} );
```

Como podran notar, tengo para exportar en PDF, en excel, imprimir y ocultar columnas. Quisiera saber si eso se puede hacer o no? gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay muchas maneras en las que puedes añadir elementos a la información que generan los botones de `print` y `pdf`.

Por ejemplo el pdf que se genera con el botón `pdf` se puede modificar con la opción `customize´, utilizando la librería de [pdfmake.org](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted)

Aquí un ejemplo de como podría quedar el botón pdf, añadiendo al principio una imagen i un texto:

```
{
  extend: 'pdfHtml5',
  text: 'PDF',
  orientation: 'portrait',
  pageSize: 'LETTER',
  title: 'Reporte de Citas Procesadas',
  exportOptions: {
    columns: ':visible',
    modifier: {
      page: 'current'
    }
  },
  customize: function(doc) {
    doc.content.splice(1, 0, {
      columns: [{
        margin: 12,
        alignment: 'left',
        image: 'data:image/png;base64,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',
        width: 50,
        height: 50
      }, {
        margin: [10, 15],
        text: 'Esto puede contener informacion del usuario',
        fontSize: 15
      }]
    });
  }
}
```

La única particularidad de la imagen es que tiene que ser codificada en base64, si tienes una `url` tendrás que convertirla.

Para la opción print, se utiliza igualmente la opción `customize`, la diferencia es que el contenido de esta se puede modificar como cualquier elemento de `html`.

Un ejemplo del botón print, añadiendo un simplemente un texto:

```
{
  extend: 'print',
  text: 'IMPRIMIR',
  exportOptions: {
    columns: ':visible'
  },
  customize: function(window) {
    $(window.document.body).children().eq(0).after('<p>Esto puede ser un elemento html</p>');
  }
}
```

Puedes ver los ejemplos funcionando en [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1pAb6RHfmSK4QhgxvOsB?p=preview).

Answer (score -1):

[Aqui](https://datatables.net/reference/button/print) puedes encontrar informacion requerida para lo que deseas.

Comment: Si en ese enlace está la respuesta deberías poner aquí el código y las esplicaciones necesarias para que la información siempre este disponible. Si por alguna razón el enlace se rompe o cambia el contenido que hay en él la respuesta dejará de ser válida.

Comment: @blonfu lo siento, no pude probar el codigo, por eso no puse la respuesta. Al tener tiempo pruebo el codigo, ojala no sea muy tarde. Pero ese link tiene buena informacion sobre los botones del plugin Datatables

Comment: Puedes poner el link pero también nos gusta que esté aquí la información para que no se pierda y la respuesta sea válida aún si el enlace no funcionase por cualquier motivo.